# Standard UIBarButtonItem Overflow Menu Icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

**What is the "standard" icon to show users when there are more menu options that couldn't fit in the `UINavigationBar`s `UIBarButtonItem` array?**

In my app there are 3 UIBarButtonItem options up top, but there are several more actions that can be performed on the screen.  Right now I use the `UIBarButtonSystemItemAction` button in the top right corner of the `UINavigationBar` to get to the overflow options.  Tapping this opens a `UIActionSheet` containing the overflow menu options.

Several users have complained that the `UIBarButtonSystemItemAction` is used for "Sharing" content to social media, etc, and therefore they don't realize this contains the overflow menu.  Is there a "standard" icon to use for something like this?  I couldn't find anything in the Apple docs.

I'm targeting iOS 7 if that changes your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard for this.

You could, however, use a UIBarButtonItem with a title of "..."

```
UIBarButtonItem *overFlowItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"..." style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showOverFlowMenu:)];
```

Comment: I like that idea!  I think I'll do that - it's pretty obvious what it means.  Still can't believe there isn't a system provided icon for this.  The Action one makes sense to me as a developer, but I can see how it would confuse people who are used to using that for sharing things.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple's opinion would be, if you can't fit everything on the toolbar then you're doing something wrong design wise...

Comment: I will mark it as correct, I'm just curious if anyone else is going to weigh in :).  I'm also sure you're right about what apple would say, but...there are so many options on that screen, it would be insane to try to do it another way.

Comment: Also look at how tabBarControllers handle this for inspiration. (The music app for an example)

Comment: Great idea. You can tweak it a bit by using nicer dots from the character chooser (CTRL+CMD+SPACE) and put "thin spaces" between them, like this: • • •